# R matrix to dataframe with all combinations

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

Looking for the simplest method to take a matrix, and convert into a dataframe where each row represents one of the unique combinations of the matrix.

Where this comes in handy is that sometimes I may create something like a distance matrix. But end-users will want a table like layout (e.g. in Excel) so they can filter and look at individual scenarios and how different they are.

1) How the initial matrix might look

```
        Honda Dodge Ferrari
Honda       0     4      10
Dodge       4     0      10
Ferrari    10    10       0
```

2) The output (acceptable) I would like to produce

```
    vehicle1 vehicle2 distance
1    Honda    Honda        0
2    Honda    Dodge        4
3    Honda  Ferrari       10
4    Dodge    Honda        4
5    Dodge    Dodge        0
6    Dodge  Ferrari       10
7  Ferrari    Honda       10
8  Ferrari    Dodge       10
9  Ferrari  Ferrari        0
```

3) The output (best case scenario) I would like to produce.
   This version omits order being important and excludes vehicle1/vehicle2 having same type (e.g. Honda, Honda, 0)

```
    vehicle1 vehicle2 distance
1    Honda    Dodge        4
2    Honda  Ferrari       10
3    Dodge  Ferrari       10
```

---

Code to reproduce:

```
#This is just to set-up outputs for display
matrix_input = matrix(c(0,4,10,4,0,10,10,10,0), nrow=3)
colnames(matrix_input) = c('Honda','Dodge','Ferrari')
rownames(matrix_input) = c('Honda','Dodge','Ferrari')

dataframe_output = data.frame(vehicle1=c("Honda","Honda", "Honda",
                                         "Dodge","Dodge", "Dodge",
                                         "Ferrari","Ferrari", "Ferrari"),  
                              vehicle2=c("Honda","Dodge", "Ferrari",
                                         "Honda","Dodge", "Ferrari",
                                         "Honda","Dodge", "Ferrari"),
                              distance=c(0,4,10,
                                         4,0,10,
                                         10,10,0))

dataframe_output.best_case = data.frame(vehicle1=c("Honda","Honda","Dodge"),
                                        vehicle2=c("Dodge","Ferrari","Ferrari"),
                                        distance=c(4,10,10))

#(1) initial matrix format
print(matrix_input)

#(2) desired output1 (acceptable)
print(dataframe_output)

#(3) desired output2 (best case)
#Ideally, I would like the operation to only pull unique 
# combinations (where order does not matter) AND exclude same values (e.g. Honda,Honda)
print(dataframe_output.best_case)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like a combination of `which(..., arr.ind=TRUE)` and `unique` (or `duplicated`) would be enough.

Comment: This is a pure R question, not RStudio, don't use the rstudio tag.

Comment: Assuming you are dealing with symmetric matrix, check the lower.tri() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shorter version to solve this problem using melt from the reshap2 package:

```
# load magrittr to use the pipe operator. 
library(magrittr)

# remove duplications (this makes sure every pair only appears once)
matrix_input[upper.tri(matrix_input)] <- NA

# melt the data.frame
df <- reshape2::melt(matrix_input, na.rm = TRUE)

# get rid of the zeros and rename variables
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(!(value == 0)) %>%
  dplyr::rename(vehicle1 = Var1, 
                vehicle2 = Var2, 
                distance = value)
```

Comment: So much cleaner than my old solution to this - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution (I'm sure its the long way around the barn). Was hoping there might be a nice 1 or 2 lines of code or some existing package I could leverage, but ended up doing it with code below. I'm all ears if someone chimes in with a simpler way.

```
#Summary: 
#This function takes a square matrix as input 
# and returns a dataframe with all 'true' combinations.

#Notes:
#(1) Loops through each row, excluding the last row.
#    Once we get to last row, all combinations will have been covered.
#(2) For each row, we start at the column +1 to right of the matrix diagonal.
#    Everything to left of diagonal (per row) will have already been covered.
#    Everything ON the diagonal will be comparing to itself, which we don't need.

m_comb_to_df = function(m, cat1, cat2, val_type) #matrix combinations to dataframe
{
  #Calc total combinations (this will be total values right of diagonal in matrix)
  #For example, if 4x4 matrix, then total combinations will be 3+2+1
  #Formula for this is ((n-1)^2+(n-1))/2
  comb = (((nrow(m)-1)^2)+(nrow(m)-1))/2

  #create new dataframe for storing matrix combinations
  df = data.frame(rep(NA, comb), rep(NA, comb), rep(NA, comb))
  colnames(df)=c(cat1, cat2, val_type)

  dfr = 1                   #dataframe row counter (start at first row)
  for(r in 1:(nrow(m)-1))   #loop through each row (except last)                  
  {                           
    for(c in (r+1):ncol(m)) #loop through columns, starting at right of diagonal (r+1)              
    {
      #print(paste(r,c,r+1)) #debug
      #store a single combination in current row (dfr) of dataframe
      df[[cat1]][dfr] = rownames(m)[r]    #store 'current' matrix row name
      df[[cat2]][dfr] = colnames(m)[c]    #store 'current' matrix column name
      df[[val_type]][dfr] = m[r,c]        #store 'current' matrix value
      dfr = dfr + 1                                
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

#matrix for testing
matrix_input = matrix(c(0,4,10,4,0,10,10,10,0), nrow=3)
colnames(matrix_input) = c('Honda','Dodge','Ferrari')
rownames(matrix_input) = c('Honda','Dodge','Ferrari')

#test function
m_comb_to_df(matrix_input, "car1", "car2", "distance")
```